# Fastest way to search ASCII files in C# for simple keywords?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, io

Right now, I search ASCII files for simple keywords like this:

```
int SearchInFile (string file, string searchString)
{
    int num = 0;

    StreamReader reader = File.OpenText (file);
    string line = reader.ReadLine();

    while (line != null)
    {
        int count = CountSubstrings(line, searchString);
        if (count != 0)
        {
            num += count;
        }
        line = reader.ReadLine();
    }

    reader.Close();

    return num;
}
```

Is this the fastest, most memory efficient way to do it? Returning the count is optional if it's going to make a huge difference in the way of searching, but not on its own.

I use it like:

```
SearchInFile ( "C:\\text.txt", "cool" );
```

Comment: What you have now should work fine for most practical purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In unmanaged code the most effective way from the performance side will be to use [Memory-Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx) instead of reading the file in buffer. I am sure that the best results can be achieved only in the way, especially if the file which you want to scan could be a file from the remote storage (a file from the server).

I am not sure that the usage of the corresponding .NET 4.0 [classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) will be in your case exactly the same effective.

Comment: Memory mapped files are now available in .NET too. (.net 4.0)

Comment: @Eric Falsken: I know that Memory mapped files are now available in .NET 4.0, follow the link from the last sentences of my answer. But the distinguish is that in unmanaged code `MapViewOfFile` get you a **pointer** of memory which represent (as the paged file) the file. You can directly use any functions for searching substring using the pointer. In .NET the `CreateViewAccessor` and `CreateViewStream` more designed **for reading the part of the file contain** additionally. So more overhead will be produced during allocation of additional memory.

Answer (score 4):

Just load the text file into a large string using StreamReader's [ReadToEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method and use string.IndexOf():

```
string test = reader.ReadToEnd();

test.indexOf("keyword")
```

Comment: Thanks, you think it would be faster? Can I clean the memory right after explicitly?

Comment: This could be faster, but is dangerous for very large files because the user's computer might not have enough memory.

Comment: @Joan didn't specified that he want's to search in large files. 
For large files he must use some of specific algorithm like Rabin–Karp string search algorithm or Boyer–Moore algorithm.

Comment: Yeah, depends on the size of the file. You also might want to use the TPL to parallelize the reading/searching of the lines. You can use the Pipeline pattern to set it up to run as quickly as possible.

Comment: what's the difference between a "large" string a normal one? :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want more performance (processing files on the order of hundreds of MB or GB), then instead of doing a line-by-line search, you should read in strings by blocks of perhaps 1k and do searches on them. Despite having to deal with some boundary conditions, this should prove faster.

That being said, you should apply a profiler like ANTS to see if this is actually your bottleneck.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kstw824%28v=VS.90%29.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.IO.STREAMREADER.READ%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V3.5%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true